# How can I iterate over an array in a Svelte store?

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte, svelte-store

I have an array in `store.ts`

```
export let annotations = writable(new Array<Annotation>());
```

And I'd like to iterate over the array, in `component.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { annotations } from '../store';
</script>

<section>
  {#each annotations as highlight, index}
    ...
  {/each}
</section>
```

This fails with:

> Argument of type 'Writable<Annotation[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike'

Which makes sense - The `Writable` object isn't a regular Array, it's a `Writable`.

**How can I iterate over an array in a Svelte store?**

Comment: See https://svelte.dev/docs#4_Prefix_stores_with_$_to_access_their_values. You'd just replace `annotations` with `$annotations` in the markup.

Comment: @101arrowz that works perfectly  Could you add it as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration over the array, in `component.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { annotations } from '../store';
</script>

<section>
  {#each $annotations as highlight, index}
    ...
  {/each}
</section>
```

[More info](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions)